# Range of the given function:

Tags: functions

Given the function

$$y=f(x)=\frac{x^2-9}{x-3},$$

I'd like to find its range.

I tried to find the range by first expressing $x$ in terms of $y$, but then I realized it's not possible to do so in this case. In what other way can I find the range of this function?

Comment: Hint: $x^2$ and $9$ are both squares. If you can think of a formula expressing the difference of two squares, you can simplify the formula. But when is $f(x)$ undefined?

Comment: I can express x²-9 as (x+3)(x-3)

Comment: Good job. How might you use that to simplify the whole equation?

Comment: I can simplify it as {(x+3)(x-3)}/(x-3)

Comment: And then what :)

Comment: Can I cancel (x-3) in numerator in denominator?

Comment: Yes, except in *one case*. If you can think of that one case, you've pretty much finished the problem.

Comment: Well, the only exception I can think of is, when (x-3)=0 i.e when x=3. This makes the denominator 0 and y=infinity. Am I correct?

Comment: Absolutely! Well deduced. So can you put it all together? If you know that $f(x)=x+3$ but $x$ can't be $3$ then what values can you get from that function?

Comment: $x=3$ would make the denominator $0$, so $f(3)$ *undefined*

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You are, ofc, correct but it's good to tackle one problem at a time. And it's enough for OP to know that $x=3$ causes an exception. And yes, that was a typo.

Comment: Well, f(x)=x+3 when x not equal to 3, which implies that y=x+3 when x not equal to 3, which implies that x=y-3 when x not equal to 3, which implies that y-3 not equal  to 3, which implies y not equal to 3+3=6. So, y cannot be 6.

Comment: So the range is R-{6}, right?

Comment: @UserKunal123 Sure is. Nicely done :)

Comment: Haha! Well, that was fun, thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Simplify $$\frac{x^2-9}{x-3}=\frac{(x-3)(x+3)}{x-3}$$ if $x\neq 3$

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out $y=\frac{x^2-9}{x-3}=x+3$ when $x\ne 3$. Since $3$ is not in the domain, that means that $3+3=6$ is not in the range. So the range is all real numbers except for $6$. In interval notation, $y\in (-\infty, 6) \cup (6, \infty)$